# TelemetryClient.Flush performance issues

Tags: c#, azure-application-insights, .net-4.6

We use the Application Insights framework within our application do keep track of events, exceptions etc.

After installing "Security Update Microsoft Windows (KB4515383)" we are experiencing performance issues on some computers.
We use the TelemetryClient.Flush method when, for example, we are closing down the application.
Since the security update, this method runs much slower than it did before we installed the update.
It now takes roughly 20 seconds to run compared to less than a second earlier.

We use version 2.4.0 of Application Insights.

I have not yet been able to figure out why only some machines are affected.

Has anyone experienced something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think 2.4.0 may have older TLS protocols used, so new security update limits this communication. AI SDK 2.5 dropped support for .NET 4.0 target that could've affected the way default TLS is selected. In AI SDK 2.5+, .NET decides on which TLS to use (should be latest all the time).

Comment: I think you are on to something. 
I updated to a later version of AI and the problem seem to have gone away.